# Storing variables in a vector using push_back

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I'm trying to store partial sums in a vector, using push_back and a for loop, however push_back causes an infinite loop for some reason.

```cpp
cin >> n;

vector <int> partialSums(n);

for (i = 1; i <= partialSums.size(); ++i) {
    sum = sum + i;
    partialSums.push_back(sum);
    cout << sum << endl;
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Why not `i <= n`?

Comment: To find out what's happening, you should print `partialSums.size()` just after `vector <int> partialSums(n);`.

Comment: Please format your code and provide a compilable example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create the vector with a specific size (`n` elements). But then you use `push_back` which adds *new* elements and resize the vector. That means `partialSums.size()` will increase each iteration and you will have your infinite loop.

Either use `i - 1` as an index to set the elements:

```
partialSums[i - 1] = sum;
```

Or just [*reserve*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) the capacity needed.

Or, as mentioned in a comment, use `i <= n` as the condition, as `n` doesn't change in the loop.